# Racket class constructor with logic

Tags: class, racket

I'm curious if there is a preferred way to write class initialization in Racket.

If we need to check some invariant, what is the preferred way:

1. In the class definition:

   ```lisp
   (class object%
     (init age)

     (when (<= age 0)
       (error "Age cannot be 0 or less."))

     (define age- age))
   ```
2. Or as a manually-written constructor function:

   ```lisp
   (define (mk-class age)
     (if (<= age 0)
       (error "Age cannot be 0 or less.")
       #| construct new instance of class |#))
   ```

What is the accepted standard for this, if there is one?

Comment: [Contracts](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Object_and_Class_Contracts.html) are a very idiomatic way

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, I will have a look at contracts for classes.  While that can work in some cases, my real question is more about _where_ we write initialization expressions.

Comment: The examples use `define/contract`; I prefer using a `contract-out` clause in `provide` though. https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contract-boundaries.html has some discussion on the difference.